# Having problems understanding a code about maketrans

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
def shift_string(text, shift):
    intab='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    outab=intab[shift:]+intab[:shift]
    return str.maketrans(intab, outab)


shift_string("hello",5)
```

When i run this, a blank occurs in shell and then nothing happens, what is happening that i do not understand right now?

Comment: try printing the result of shift_string

Answer (score 1):

`maketrans` is used to create a mapping that is passed to the `.translate()` method of a string. Right now you're just returning the mapping, not the translated string.

```
def shift_string(text, shift):
    intab='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    outab=intab[shift:]+intab[:shift]
    mapping = str.maketrans(intab, outab)
    return text.translate(mapping)
```

Comment: `string.ascii_lowercase` could be used.